# DevExpress GridControl shows rows but does not show cell values

Tags: gridview, data-binding, devexpress, datasource

I have a DevExpress GridControl and I'm using an `ObservableCollection<LogEntry>` as the data source, which [according DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q384446) should work in .NET 4.

LogEntry is defined as

```
public class LogEntry
{
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Time;
    [UsedImplicitly] public string LogLevel;
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Cutpoint;
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Method;
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Parameters;
}
```

and I have set up the columns plus the binding in the Designer.

I can see that the grid gets additional rows whenever a log event arrives, but the content is empty:

[image: Empty grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used public fields instead of properties. Changing the definition to

```
public class LogEntry
{
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Time { get; set; }
    [UsedImplicitly] public string LogLevel { get; set; }
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Cutpoint { get; set; }
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Method { get; set; }
    [UsedImplicitly] public string Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

solved the problem.